# Delphi TDateTimePicker issue, "failed to set min/max range"

Tags: delphi, tdatetimepicker

A few users of an app of mine are having a weird issue, on start-up they get an Exception with the datitimepickers which have a predetermined min/max date set to 01 Jan 1950 - 31 Dec 2050.

The default error message thrown by the app is

> "Error reading time1.Max: Failed to set calendar min/max range."

Upon embedding a debugger (madshi's madExcept) I see in the report:

> "Error reading time1.MaxDate: '23:59:59' is not a valid date and
>   time."

The object on the form has these properties:

> ```
>             Date = 39773.494141041670000000
>             Format = 'MMM yyyy'
>             Time = 39773.494141041670000000
>             MaxDate = 55153.999988425920000000
>             MinDate = 18264.000000000000000000
> ```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Crash data:

main thread ($2b08):

```
> 0051501b +0a7 app.exe System.Classes 10430   +5 HandleException
> 00515255 +1f5 app.exe System.Classes 10487  +48 TReader.ReadProperty
> 00514a65 +015 app.exe System.Classes 10233   +1 TReader.ReadDataInner
> 00514a47 +067 app.exe System.Classes 10226  +11 TReader.ReadData
> 0051de05 +001 app.exe System.Classes 15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState
> 0057d017 +02f app.exe Vcl.Controls    5567   +3 TControl.ReadState
> 00581481 +025 app.exe Vcl.Controls    8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState
> 005148bf +11f app.exe System.Classes 10187  +23 TReader.ReadComponent
> 00514ad9 +089 app.exe System.Classes 10241   +9 TReader.ReadDataInner
> 00514a47 +067 app.exe System.Classes 10226  +11 TReader.ReadData
> 0051de05 +001 app.exe System.Classes 15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState
> 0057d017 +02f app.exe Vcl.Controls    5567   +3 TControl.ReadState
> 00581481 +025 app.exe Vcl.Controls    8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState
> 00604c4c +028 app.exe Vcl.ExtCtrls   10464   +3
> TCustomCategoryPanel.ReadState 005148bf +11f app.exe System.Classes
> 10187  +23 TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089 app.exe System.Classes
> 10241   +9 TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a47 +067 app.exe System.Classes
> 10226  +11 TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001 app.exe System.Classes 15947
> +0 TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f app.exe Vcl.Controls    5567   +3 TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025 app.exe Vcl.Controls    8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState 005c8523 +00b app.exe Vcl.ComCtrls    6207   +1
> TTabSheet.ReadState 005148bf +11f app.exe System.Classes 10187  +23
> TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089 app.exe System.Classes 10241   +9
> TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a47 +067 app.exe System.Classes 10226  +11
> TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001 app.exe System.Classes 15947   +0
> TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f app.exe Vcl.Controls    5567   +3
> TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025 app.exe Vcl.Controls    8434   +3
> TWinControl.ReadState 005148bf +11f app.exe System.Classes 10187  +23
> TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089 app.exe System.Classes 10241   +9
> TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a18 +038 app.exe System.Classes 10220   +5
> TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001 app.exe System.Classes 15947   +0
> TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f app.exe Vcl.Controls    5567   +3
> TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025 app.exe Vcl.Controls    8434   +3
> TWinControl.ReadState 0064f15d +06d app.exe Vcl.Forms       3836  +11
> TCustomForm.ReadState 005159d7 +1d7 app.exe System.Classes 10667  +37
> TReader.ReadRootComponent 005109c6 +032 app.exe System.Classes  8269  
> +3 TStream.ReadComponent 0050a37f +057 app.exe System.Classes  3834   +7 InternalReadComponentRes 0050bcbb +05f app.exe System.Classes  3891   +4 InitComponent 0050bd49 +061 app.exe System.Classes  3903   +6 InitInheritedComponent 0064e982 +0c6 app.exe Vcl.Forms       3592  +17
> TCustomForm.Create 006593da +076 app.exe Vcl.Forms      10407  +13
> TApplication.CreateForm 008e146e +cce app.exe app       342 +211
> initialization 74e9919d +00c KERNEL32.DLL                            
> BaseThreadInitThunk
> 
> main thread ($2b08), inner exception level 1:
> >> EConvertError, '23:59:59' is not a valid date and time 0044d219 +019 app.exe System.SysUtils  5387   +1 ConvertErrorFmt 00453b74 +02c app.exe System.SysUtils 19596   +2 StrToDateTime 005dd4e1 +0f5 app.exe
> Vcl.ComCtrls    27328   +6 TCommonCalendar.SetMaxDate 004e873d +06d
> app.exe System.TypInfo   2238   +8
> {System.TypInfo}TPropSet<System.Double>.SetProc 004e729a +066 app.exe
> System.TypInfo   3185   +3 SetFloatProp 005155ff +18b app.exe
> System.Classes  10567  +25 TReader.ReadPropValue 005151f6 +196 app.exe
> System.Classes  10476  +37 TReader.ReadProperty 00514a65 +015 app.exe
> System.Classes  10233   +1 TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a47 +067 app.exe
> System.Classes  10226  +11 TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001 app.exe
> System.Classes  15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f app.exe
> Vcl.Controls     5567   +3 TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025 app.exe
> Vcl.Controls     8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState 005148bf +11f app.exe
> System.Classes  10187  +23 TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089 app.exe
> System.Classes  10241   +9 TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a47 +067 app.exe
> System.Classes  10226  +11 TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001 app.exe
> System.Classes  15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f app.exe
> Vcl.Controls     5567   +3 TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025 app.exe
> Vcl.Controls     8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState 00604c4c +028 app.exe
> Vcl.ExtCtrls    10464   +3 TCustomCategoryPanel.ReadState 005148bf
> +11f app.exe System.Classes  10187  +23 TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089 app.exe System.Classes  10241   +9 TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a47 +067 app.exe System.Classes  10226  +11 TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001 app.exe System.Classes  15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f
> app.exe Vcl.Controls     5567   +3 TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025
> app.exe Vcl.Controls     8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState 005c8523 +00b
> app.exe Vcl.ComCtrls     6207   +1 TTabSheet.ReadState 005148bf +11f
> app.exe System.Classes  10187  +23 TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089
> app.exe System.Classes  10241   +9 TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a47 +067
> app.exe System.Classes  10226  +11 TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001
> app.exe System.Classes  15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f
> app.exe Vcl.Controls     5567   +3 TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025
> app.exe Vcl.Controls     8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState 005148bf +11f
> app.exe System.Classes  10187  +23 TReader.ReadComponent 00514ad9 +089
> app.exe System.Classes  10241   +9 TReader.ReadDataInner 00514a18 +038
> app.exe System.Classes  10220   +5 TReader.ReadData 0051de05 +001
> app.exe System.Classes  15947   +0 TComponent.ReadState 0057d017 +02f
> app.exe Vcl.Controls     5567   +3 TControl.ReadState 00581481 +025
> app.exe Vcl.Controls     8434   +3 TWinControl.ReadState 0064f15d +06d
> app.exe Vcl.Forms        3836  +11 TCustomForm.ReadState 005159d7 +1d7
> app.exe System.Classes  10667  +37 TReader.ReadRootComponent 005109c6
> +032 app.exe System.Classes   8269   +3 TStream.ReadComponent 0050a37f +057 app.exe System.Classes   3834   +7 InternalReadComponentRes 0050bcbb +05f app.exe System.Classes   3891   +4 InitComponent
> 0050bd49 +061 app.exe System.Classes   3903   +6
> InitInheritedComponent 0064e982 +0c6 app.exe Vcl.Forms        3592 
> +17 TCustomForm.Create 006593da +076 app.exe Vcl.Forms       10407  +13 TApplication.CreateForm 008e146e +cce app.exe app        342 +211 initialization 74e9919d +00c KERNEL32.DLL                             
> BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"Failed to set calendar min/max range"` error means that [`DateTime_SetRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761811.aspx) failed.  It was likely given an array of invalid `SYSTEMTIME` values as just a side effect of the `MaxDate` property failing to load its value from the DFM properly.

The `"not a valid date and time"` error comes from `StrToDateTime()`.  According to your call stack,

```
>> EConvertError, '23:59:59' is not a valid date and time 0044d219 +019 app.exe
System.SysUtils  5387   +1 ConvertErrorFmt 00453b74 +02c app.exe
System.SysUtils 19596   +2 StrToDateTime 005dd4e1 +0f5 app.exe
Vcl.ComCtrls    27328   +6 TCommonCalendar.SetMaxDate 004e873d +06d app.exe
```

`SetMaxDate()` is calling `StrToDateTime()`.  I have never seen `TDateTimePicker` do that before, so I checked the VCL source and found that the call was added in XE5 (and still exists in the recently released XE6):

```
procedure TCommonCalendar.SetMaxDate(Value: TDate);
begin
  if (FMinDate <> 0.0) and (Value < FMinDate) then
    raise CalExceptionClass.CreateFmt(SDateTimeMin, [DateToStr(FMinDate)]);
  if FMaxDate <> Value then
  begin
    Value := Trunc(Value);
    Value := Value + StrToDateTime('23:59:59'); // <-- HERE
    SetRange(FMinDate, Value);
    FMaxDate := Value;
  end;
end;
```

Prior to XE5, `SetMaxDate()` looked like this instead:

```
procedure TCommonCalendar.SetMaxDate(Value: TDate);
begin
  if (FMinDate <> 0.0) and (Value < FMinDate) then
    raise CalExceptionClass.CreateFmt(SDateTimeMin, [DateToStr(FMinDate)]);
  if FMaxDate <> Value then
  begin
    SetRange(FMinDate, Value);
    FMaxDate := Value;
  end;
end;
```

That was just plain **stupid** on Embarcadero's part, because `StrToDateTime()` is subject to user locale settings.  Obviously, the time format on the failing machines does not match the **hard-coded** value that Embarcadero is using.  `EncodeTime()` should have been used instead:

```
Value := Value + EncodeTime(23, 59, 59, 0);
```

In fact, I think Embarcadero should have used `ReplaceTime()` as well:

```
ReplaceTime(Value, EncodeTime(23, 59, 59, 0));
```

I have filed a bug report in QC:

[#124326 MaxDate: '23:59:59' is not a valid date and time](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124326)

Until Embarcadero fixes it, you have two choices:

1. patch your VCL manually to fix the bug.  If you do not compile your app with Runtime Packages enabled, you can make a copy of Vcl.ComCtrls.pas, edit it as needed, and then add the copy to your project.  If you want a more permanent patch, you can compile the edited Vcl.ComCtrls.pas and place the new DCU file(s) in the IDE's lib folder(s).
2. leave the `MaxDate` set to 0.0 at design-time set `SetMaxDate()` will not be called at DFM load time, then set `MaxDate` manually in your code at startup, since as in the form's `OnCreate` event.  You will have to temporary change the global `SysUtils.FormatSettings` variables (most likely just `FormatSettings.TimeSeparator`) to match the format that `SetMaxDate()` is using, then assign `MaxDate` to the desired value, and then change the variables back to their original values:

   ```
   var
     TS: Char;

   TS := FormatSettings.TimeSeparator;
   FormatSettings.TimeSeparator := ':';
   try
     DateTimePicker1.MaxDate := ...;
   finally
     FormatSettings.TimeSeparator := TS;
   end;
   ```

.

Comment: Well the thing is it only happens to a few users, so I discard the DFM being corrupted, and thought it might be something with the user's regional settings maybe. I will edit the question to include the call stack.

Comment: As it turns out, it is indeed related to regional settings. It is a nasty little bug in `SetMaxDate()` that Embarcadero needs to fix. I filed a [bug report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124326) for you.

Comment: Does your suggested fix mean that datetimes in the last second of the last day will be out of range?

Comment: Ty, that's what I did to try and mitigate the issue, clear the ranges in the form and then set Min/Max at runtime with EncodeDate.

Comment: Just using `EncodeDate()` to assign the `MaxDate` will not avoid the problem, since you still have to account for the call to `StrToDateTime()` inside of the `MaxDate` setter.  I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting "Failed to set calendar min/max range." when setting the min or max dates on a TMonthCalendar control:

```
myCalendar.MinDate:= myMinDate;
```

This was resolved by casting the new value as a TDateTime;

```
myCalendar.MinDate:= TDateTime(myMinDate);
```